# How to add script to body section in Cart Page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

Magento 2.2

How can I add the following script on the cart page in BODY section:

```
dataLayer.push ({
   'Param': 'xxx',
   });
```

where XXX - Dynamically basket value, without shipping costs and discounts

Answer (score 1):

Create a frontend layout `checkout_cart_index.xml` in your custom theme or module.

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceContainer name="content">
   <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock" before="-" name="custom-script" template="Vendor_Module::script.phtml"/>
  </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

Create CustomBlock.php file in your module's block directory and add the following code.

```
$protected $_cart;  

public function __construct(
 ...
 \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
 ...
) {
 $this->_cart = $cart;
}

public function getCartSubTotal()
{
   $subTotal = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
   return $subTotal;
}
```

Create script.phtml in your template directory.

Add the following code:

```
<?php
$cartTotal = $block->getCartSubTotal();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  dataLayer.push ({
   'Param': $cartTotal,
   });  
</script>
```

**Hope this solution will work for you.**

Comment: Thanks, but XXX value must  be taken from the cart